# Android LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android

I have a layout, I want the layout to be mirrored (from right to left). I'm RTL in my application. In my class I wrote the following:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void forceRTLIfSupported() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(
                View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    }
}
```

Here is my manifest file :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.sc3v2"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0"
          >
        <uses-sdk   
            android:minSdkVersion="17" 
            android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>

        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:largeHeap="true"
             android:supportsRtl="true"
             >

            <activity 

                android:name="com.example.sc2v1.ViewPagerExampleActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                      >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity android:name="com.example.sc2v1.Glossary"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                ></activity>

        </application>
    </manifest>
```

The problem is I'm having two errors :

- The first one in my class, I'm getting "LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL cannot be resolved or is not a field"
- The second error is in the manifest "error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'supportsRtl' in package 'android'"

Any help please ?